# Put token failed. status-code: 500 error in ServiceBusSessionReceiver creation from azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, amqp, azure-managed-identity

This error is logged occasionally in the function app logs. "An exception occurred while creating a ServiceBusSessionReceiver (Namespace '<servicebus namespace>.servicebus.windows.net', Entity path '<topic>/Subscriptions/<subscription>'). Error Message: 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: Put token failed. status-code: 500, status-description: The service was unable to process the request; please retry the operation."

The function app uses managed identity to connect to the service bus.

There is no impact on the regular usage but just want to know the reason for this exception.

I checked online to find the reason for the exception but didn`t find anything even on StackOverflow. I want to know the reason for this exception so I will know the impact of the failure and try to resolve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no action needed for your application and nothing that you can do to resolve.  This is something that is handled by the Service Bus infrastructure internally.  Intermittent failures will not impact your application, though if you're seeing this in large clusters or seeing it frequently, I'd encourage you to [open a support ticket](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for investigation.

To add some context, this exception indicates a service-side issue when passing authorization token over the CBS link, which is a background activity.  The Service Bus client sends refreshes periodically with a large enough window that failures can be retried before the current authorization expires.  In the worst case, a specific connection would fault and the Service Bus client would create a new one. So long as the service issue was transient, such as is common when a service node is rebooting or being moved, things will recover without noticeable impact to the application.